# Diamond display with Nested Loops

Tags: java, nested, geometry, drawing

I've learned a lot here, but there is a question I have that I can't sem to find.

Our last assignment, requires us to use nested For Loops in Java to display a diamond.

The Program must use a symbol entered by the user and draw the following:

```
    %
   % %
  % % %
 % % % %
% % % % %
 % % % %
  % % %
   % %
    %
```

So far, i pseudo coded one half triangle, and then I was going to code the inverse of the triangle to complete the opposite side, but I can not get any other than this without increasing the amount of symbols required:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

This is the code:

```
String symbol1; //User input, symbol to utilize

Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter the Symbol you wish to use: ");
symbol1 = Keyboard.next();

for (int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
    for (int k=5 ; k > i; k--)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(symbol1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}



  }
}
```

Any input is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT********

I wanted to post my end code.
It may be simple, but I feel accomplished. 
Hopefully it will help someone at some point like I was helped here!

Cheers everyone.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlvaradoPgm04Bonus {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

//Draw a diamond using symbol entered by user

```
String symbol1; //User input, symbol to utilize

Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner (System.in); //New scanner 
System.out.println("Enter the Symbol you wish to use: "); //Prompt user symbol input
symbol1 = Keyboard.next(); // Capture user input

    for (int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){ //Begin for loop - increase until int is 5 long
        for (int k=8 ; k > i ; k--){ //nested loop - decrease space before int "i" (inverted invisible triangle)
            System.out.print(" "); //print space from nested loop before symbol1 
        }
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++){ //nested loop - increase "j" until is equal to "i" 
            System.out.print(symbol1 + " "); //print symbol1 + space to form diamond
        }
        System.out.println(); //print above nested loop line by line

    } //begin new loop - inverted triangle

    for (int m = 4 ; m > 0 ; m--){ //decrease symbol by 1
        for (int n = 8 ; n >= m ; n--){ //match increase of space "invisible" triangle next to symbol to form upside down triangle
            System.out.print(" "); //print "invisible" triangle
        }
        for (int q = 0 ; q < m ; q++){ //nested loop to decrease symbol entered by user
            System.out.print(symbol1 + " "); //print inverted triangle made of user's input
        }

        System.out.println(); //print the loop in new line.

    }       //end loop

}//end main
```

} //end class

Comment: Use a char type for the symbol rather than a string; unless you want to support symbols wider than one character.

Comment: @brano88 I wasn't looking for the answer, but rather get guided on the right path. I'm new to java so I am still getting a grip of everything there is to know and how to handle the code to do what I want. Thanks anyway. Any feedback certainly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to notice that in the expected output there are spaces after each symbol, since you know how to print a space and I would assume you know where you're printing your symbol it should be easy for you to add the printing of a space after a symbol.
Then you've got the half of the diamond, the bottom half is exactly the same In the opposIte dIrectIon If you get my hInt.

Comment: You are amazing. This is exactly what I needed. I had been going nuts trying to print a half space instead of adding the space on the figure. Not until now I realized there was a space in it, and without printing double symbols I could not get the geometry I needed. I THANK you GREATLY!!!

Answer (score 0):

package moreloops;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Diamond {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int input=in.nextInt();
    int spac=input-1;
    int min=1;
    int max=input;
    for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
        for(int k=spac ; k>i;k--){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j=0;j<min;j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        min+=2;
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int m=input-1;m>0;m--){
        for(int n=spac;n>=m;n--){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int q=0;q<m;q++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

my output lol 
5
    *

---

---

---

---

---

---

**
    *

Comment: thats ma output :(
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
 ****
  ***
   **
    *

Answer (score 0):

```
package moreloops;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Diamond {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int input=in.nextInt();
    int spac=input-1;
    int min=1;
    int max=input;
    for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
        for(int k=spac ; k>i;k--){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j=0;j<min;j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        min+=2;
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int m=input-1;m>0;m--){
        for(int n=spac;n>=m;n--){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int q=0;q<m;q++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for(int s=0;s<m-1;s++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

That will help